# Contextual help in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am not a very good at using Emacs, but the feature I would like the most would be some integration with help/documentation for a particular language/API I use at the moment. I would imagine that there would be help displayed in another buffer depending on where I put my cursor while editing.

I wonder if there is a package that does that, even if it would be very simple, just displaying some file based on the keyword. I think there is, but I cannot find it ("help" is a too generic word).

(In particular, I would like to have this help for Common Lisp, but other languages, such as Java or C, could be useful.)

Comment: In addition to what has been written, **Icicles** can help with help: <http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNewbieWithIcicles>

Answer (score 1):

ILISP and SLIME provide several methods for looking up a function; see [the Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CommonLispHyperspec) and [the SLIME documentation](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Documentation.html#Documentation).  Or just built into Emacs itself, there are functions like `C-h f` to get function help or `M-x man`; both use the text at the point by default.  You could pretty easily adapt them to work for another language of your choice.

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely useful information, although I was looking for something more automatic and generic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SLIME for common-lisp, you can take a look at [`slime-autodoc-mode`](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/slime_002dautodoc_002dmode.html).

Sorry, can't help with a generic solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the CLHS root for SLIME in your `.emacs` file:

```
(setq common-lisp-hyperspec-root "/usr/share/doc/hyperspec/HyperSpec/")
```

Adjust the path to where you put your HyperSpec.

Then, `C-c C-d h` with point at a symbol will look it up there in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might like to enable is eldoc-mode, by adding `(turn-on-eldoc-mode)` to your mode hook functions for the appropriate programming modes.

```
In ElDoc mode, the echo area displays information about a
function or variable in the text where point is.  If point is
on a documented variable, it displays the first line of that
variable's doc string.  Otherwise it displays the argument list
of the function called in the expression point is on.
```

This is probably less than you were after, but it still makes a good companion to a fuller-featured contextual help system, and there are a number of programming modes that support it.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I was looking for, although other suggestions are very helpful too. I'll try it.